# Highstock - multiple plotlines value from json

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

i need help with use multiple lines on xaxis. I know how to add multiple line if i use like this

```
xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            value: Date.UTC(2011,1,1, 12,00,00),
            width: 1,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
        },
    {
            value: Date.UTC(2011,5,1, 12,00,00),
            width: 1,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
        },
    {
            value: Date.UTC(2011,8,1, 12,00,00),
            width: 1,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
        }
    ]
    }
```

i need to use this way, taking data from api

```
$scope.hiddenSeries = [
[Date.UTC(2016,7,1, 12,00,00)],
[Date.UTC(2016,6,1, 12,00,00)],
[Date.UTC(2016,5,1, 12,00,00)],
[Date.UTC(2016,4,1, 12,00,00)],
];

        $scope.chartConfig1 = {
            xAxis: {
                ordinal: false,
                plotLines: [{
            value: $scope.hiddenSeries,
            width: 1,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash'
        }]
```

This way not working, not showing any data. I try to google it, but all example is like in first case.

Comment: Are you sure you need AngularJS specific function for this thask? Using just JavaScript you could loop over your `hiddenSeries` array and create a `plotLines` array - one plot line for each date.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx @kacper madej
I fix this on this way.I add full spec in $scope.

```
$scope.hiddenSeries = [
{value: Date.UTC(2016,6,1), width: 1, color: 'green', dashStyle: 'dash'},
{value: Date.UTC(2016,7,1), width: 1, color: 'green', dashStyle: 'dash'},
{value: Date.UTC(2016,7,7), width: 1, color: 'green', dashStyle: 'dash'}
];
```

and in $scope.chartConfig1 in xAxis defined

```
plotLines: $scope.hiddenSeries
```